# Is there a way to know the class name via instance method? Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

So lets assume i have a class method `call_me_once`. Is there any method to check the name of the class?

Such as `call_me_once.my_class_name`?

Comment: Class of what? Class of the return value of the method? Class/module that the method was defined in? Class/module that you’re currently in? An expanded example with expected output may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the class name of the methods there are two easy ways to achieve this and each method depends on what type of method you have. If it's a class method then you can use `Method#receiver` like:

```
class Test
  def cls_method
    puts "Class Method"
  end

  def some_method
    puts "Instance Method"
  end
end

Test.method(:cls_method).receiver # => Test
```

And if you're dealing with an instance method then you're going to need to use the `Method#owner` method:

```
Test.instance_method(:some_method).owner # => Test
```

If you do not know if you're receiving a class or instance method beforehand you can check to see if the method will respond to `receiver` which class methods will and instance methods will not.

Answer (score 0):

The class can be checked by using

```
call_me_once.class
```